# Get phone number in textfield to make a phone call when pressing a button

Tags: ios, button, textfield, phone-call

The application simply wants to make a user input a phone number in a text field and then when a button is tapped, it'll call that number. What's the best code for this? I have already created a button and a textfield in my nib file.

I'm using Xcode 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Phone) shows you how to do it.  Just make the NSMutableString phone go to your text field (by using `yourTextField.text`)

Comment: Thanks. Is this the correct code to use?
NSMUtableString *phone = yourTextField.text;
and then this:

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phone]];
?

Comment: You don't need to make it an NSMutableString, it can just be an NSString, and you don't even need that!  You could just use `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", yourTextField.text]];` and it'll work (just be sure to open that URL :) )

Answer (score 2):

```
-(IBAction)numberButtonPressed:(UIButton *)pressedButton
{

    self.phoneNumberLabel.text = [self.phoneNumberLabel.text stringByAppendingString: pressedButton.titleLabel.text];

}
```

You can take a look at turorial here:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/design-build-a-1980s-ios-phone-app-making-phone-calls/